# cp command not executing after running other script inside bash script .

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell-script

There is `cp` commands inside my shell-script after following commands

```
 echo 'Starting Jboss server !!!' 
 (eval "sh standalone.sh --debug")
 cp /soure_file_path  /target_path 
 sleep 60s
```

`sh standalone.sh --debug` running correctly but after that `cp` commands not getting execute after `60`seconds.

Comment: @A.B `--debug` is command to run wildfly server in debug mode . It is working fine but after this , copy command  (`cp`) not running which is suppose to be run after 60s

Answer (score 1):

Change your script to the following:

```
echo 'Starting Jboss server !!!' 
nohup sh standalone.sh --debug &
sleep 60s
cp /soure_file_path /target_path
```

This way you run the command in another process, and as a plus it won't mess up your console output either (if you do need the output, just remove `nohup`). Then it will sleep for 60 seconds, then do the copying.
If you need to terminate the JBoss server, then you can find the process running the `standalone.sh`, and terminate it with *SIGTERM*.

Comment: this is working fine but , i want to have `logs` to be printed on console.

Comment: Then just don't use `nohup`, only the `&`